# How to pass variables values between classes

Tags: c++, class, oop, variables

So i'm doing a little project just for fun ( since in my class we aren't doing anything interesting at all) that tries to copy the combat system of an old RPG and i came across this problem: i have 2 classes and one needs the value of a variable from the other class. I'm still a little bit new though so please don't take anything for granted. Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

class Moveset
{
    int pp;
    int precision;
    std::string moveName;
public:
    bool hit(int precision)
    {
        srand(time(0));
        int randomNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if (randomNumber <= precision && randomNumber >= 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    void scratch(float &HP)
    {
        pp = 15;
        precision = 80;
        moveName = "scratch";

        bool success = hit(precision);


        //here i want to replace the question marks with the playerName from
        //the player class, but how can i do that?

        std::cout << "??? used " << moveName << " !" << std::endl;
        pp--;

        if (success)
        {
            HP = HP - 20;

            std::cout << "HP: " << HP << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "It missed!" << std::endl;
        }
    }

};

class Player
{
public:

    float HP;
    std::string playerName;
    int age;
    Moveset ptr0;
};

int main()
{

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 0:
            std::cout << "Welcome to the test of this special combat system!" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 1:
            std::cout << "In this small test you'll have access of a prototype of it!" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "Now get ready and experience the first version ever! Go!" << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            break;

        }
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
    }

    Moveset Move;
    Player Niko;
    Niko.HP = 100;
    Niko.playerName = "Niko";
    Niko.ptr0 = Move;
    Niko.ptr0.scratch(Niko.HP);
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: What specifically do you want?  Does the code above compile?  If it compiles, what does it do that you don't like?  If it doesn't compile, please post the exact error message.

Comment: Nono the code as it is now works perfectly fine, the thing that I want is that instead of the question marks ( "??? used ") I want to say the actual playerName from the player class but i have no idea how to do that without causing errors.

Answer (score 1):

Better use object, like this:

```
void scratch(Player &p)
```

So you'll have all the player data, not only the HP.

You'll have a cross dependency between the `Player` and the `Moveset` classes but that is other problem, you can also keep a reference to the `Player` in the `Moveset` it own, or work with interfaces.

Comment: And then you'd say `Niko.ptr0.scratch(Niko);` to call it

Comment: This could work but the problem is that since player is decleared after scratch the result is that p is undecleared and since i decleared a pointer inside the player class that use the Moveset class i can't place it before the Moveset class unless I delete it and change the whole code but experiencing pointers that point to classes was my aim here so that wouldn't be what i'd like to do :/ .

Comment: Calling something ptr0 does not make it a pointer.  You haven't declared any pointers anywhere in your code (you declare a pointer with `<type>*<name>`).  You assignment `Niko.ptr0 = Move` invokes an implicit copy constructor for Moveset so nothing is undeclared.  If you want to experience pointers to objects you will need to replace `Moveset ptr0` with `Moveset * ptr0` and change your access to `Niko.ptr0->scratch(Niko.HP)`

Comment: Also, if you are concerned about referring to the `Player` class in the `Moveset` class then just use a forward declaration.  Shift the `Player`  class above `Moveset` and then before the `Player` class definition add the `class Moveset;` forward declaration.  You will need to change `ptr0` to be an actual pointer as I described above.  This is because `Player` can only include `Moveset` as an incomplete type if it does not need to know the size of it (all pointers are the same size).  There are much better ways to write something like this however and I would look at the whole approach.

Comment: I'm looking to improve so what do you think would be the best approach to use in this case? ( thank you very much)